# Breaking async/await flow

Tags: typescript, async-await

I am writing testcases for selenium in our own test automation framework.
Because i want to know what our framework is doing, i have added some logging to the console that will also be added to our test report.

For this i have written the following function

```
async error(message?: any, indent?: boolean) {
    const datetime = timeUtils.generateTimestampForLogging();
    indent = indent == undefined ? true : indent;

    this.mycon.info(`${CYAN}${indent ? '\t' : ''}${datetime} :: ERROR :: ${message} ${RESET} `);

    if (this._world != undefined) {
      await this._world.attach(`<span style="color:forestgreen;">${datetime} :: ERROR :: ${message}</span>`, 'text/html');
    }
  }
```

To attach the data to the test report, i have to use async/await.
However, i don't want to make the 'error' function asynchronous since i also use it in places that expect a non-promise return value.
Like here
[image]
Is there a way to keep the 'error' function non-async and still wait for the 'attach' call?

Like this? [image]

Comment: Don't post images of code, write the code directly in the post, with the proper formating.

Comment: Oh ok, sorry. i just wanted to visualize what was going wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `fs` with promises, use the `fs.promises` object rather than the callback-based API:

```
async function createIfNotExists(path: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
        // instead of passing an error object to a callback, this throws on error
        await fs.promises.access(path);
    } catch {
        // here, we know an error occurred with the access
        await fs.promises.mkdir(path, { recursive: true });
    }
}
```